# Jcoverflip calling the Next method from jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Tryin to call the next method:

http://www.jcoverflip.com/documentation/advance-customization#section-methods

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        jQuery('#flip').jcoverflip();

        $('#right').click(function() {
           var i =  jQuery('#flip').jcoverflip();
           i.next();
        });
    });      
</script>
```

but does nothing

Answer (score 3):

The methods you're after are widget methods, called like this:

```
jQuery("#flip").jcoverflip("next");
```

The first parameter is the method name, the optional parameters are passed as the 2nd, 3rd, etc. arguments.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#next-button').click(function() { 
  $('#flip').jcoverflip('next'); 
});
```

Paste this into document ready function.